# Can we return temporary table from function instead of table variable?

Tags: sql-server, temp-tables

I have a function...in which I have return type as table variable...
But performance will be increased if we use temp tables..as we have more data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot "return" a temp table - you can create that temp table before calling your function, and have your function write data into that temp table.

But this has a tendency to get rather messy .... you need to make sure to have the temp table created before calling the function.....

Have you really, honestly **measured** the performance of the two approaches?? I don't think temp tables are just always faster.... the approach with the table variable seems a lot cleaner and more intuitive to me.

Comment: @Anish: there's no generally clear answer; you need to try it and measure for yourself - it depends on your structure, your data, the amount of data, your hardware.... just too many factors - cannot say for sure - test and measure!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot of course return the temp table. But you can define it in the calling stored procedure. Bear in mind this will *only* work for stored procedures. You cannot access temporary tables from within functions.

Comment: **Define = create and possibly populate.** Make sure you use `##tableName` to ensure the table is accessible globally (outside of the current SPID.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CLR Table Valued functions that returns the actual table. CLR functions are functions you can write in your native language C#, VB etc. and the dll are embedded in the database.

Learn more about it from here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131103.aspx

Answer (score 0):

this cover just about every way with pros/cons and sample code:

[How to Share Data Between Stored Procedures  by Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html)

```
Using OUTPUT Parameters
Table-valued Functions
    Inline Functions
    Multi-statement Functions
Using a Table
    Sharing a Temp Table
    Process-keyed Table
    Global Temp Tables
INSERT-EXEC
Table Parameters and Table Types
Using the CLR
OPENQUERY
Using XML
Using Cursor Variables
```